# Uptime from several checkpoint at once

Tags: apache-2.4

i'm trying to validate my website from multiple locations at once using https://www.uptrends.com/tools/uptime, I'm getting http timeout. I don't know why isn't working properly...

Hope you can help me out.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try to avoid direct links to your services, as they may be considered spam or cause you security issues, depending on the type of issue you are having. Instead, be as specific as you can and show every test you did. Try other services for the same feature you are testing.

Comment: @Leo On the other hand including that information will generally make it much more likely that anybody will be able to answer the question.

Comment: @Leo See also [here](https://meta.serverfault.com/q/963/126632).

Answer (score 1):

That testing service by default tests connectivity to your server from 41 different locations in parallel. And it appears that your server simply doesn't have the capacity to handle 41 simultaneous clients.

While the test is not running it takes 1-2 seconds for your server to serve `https://perfilaberturas.com.ar/`. Attempting to access the site while the test is running means the server will have to process 42 requests in parallel.

Under those circumstances it takes your server more than 20 seconds to respond to the first request and likely more than a minute before it responds to the last. The test service has a 30 seconds timeout after which it (quite reasonably) declares your site to be down. And even after the test has timed out the request your server is still spending resources on those requests as a single request started in parallel with the test would still be pending for a long time after the test had finished.

Taking more than 1 second to respond to an initial user request under no load is bad for user experience. And your server crumbling under the load of 41 simultaneous requests means it is quite vulnerable to DoS attacks (intentional or unintentional).

So what you need to do is to find out why the server need so many resources to render that page and fix that.